# Multiplying the current value of a variable

Tags: python

Write a statement that assigns cell_count with cell_count multiplied by 10. * performs multiplication. If the input is 10, the output should be:
100

```
cell_count = int(input())

''' Your solution goes here '''

print(cell_count)
```

I am putting cell_count * 10 and its not the correct answer, can someone help me.

Comment: Maybe cell_count*=10

Comment: are you assigning the changed value to the variable cell_count ? `cell_count = cell_count * 10`

Comment: Please strongly consider to do the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: *Where* are you putting ``cell_count * 10``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing `cell_count * 10` is the correct calculation, but since you are not assigning it back to the variable `cell_count`, it remains the same as earlier and that's why your answer is showing incorrect.

To understand, if we say a = 2 and then a+1 is 3, but a is still 2, to make a = 3, you will have to do a a = a+1.

So there are two approaches:

The simplest is

```
cell_count = cell_count * 10
```

Another more efficient way is `cell_count *= 10`, `*=` is a special character in python which multiplies and assigns to itself in one single operation.

Answer (score 0):

It can be

```
cell_count *= 10
```

or

```
cell_count = cell_count*10
```

Comment: Can I kindly ask you to accept my answer if it was correct as I were the first to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to assign value back to the variable, so you can use the output. You can try this:

> ```
> cell_count = int(input())
>
> cell_count *= 10
> ```

or this:

> ```
> cell_count = int(input())
>
> cell_count = cell_count * 10
> ```

Answer (score -1):

for posterity:

---

cell_count = int(input()) <-- line 1 which can not be edited

cell_count = cell_count * int(10)   <--- my line

print(cell_count)  <---- line that can not be edited

---

is the answer I input and was accepted.

Comment: why would you repeat an already accepted answer which dates back several months or even years? This is not good practise and will not help your reputations